# Error when trying to install dotnet tools

Tags: .net-core

I'm trying to install Microsoft.dotnet-interactive tool but have this issue,

Also tried with different tools same issue

I tried the following commands

> dotnet tool install --global Microsoft.dotnet-interactive
>   dotnet tool install --global Microsoft.dotnet-interactive --version 1.0.110520
>   dotnet tool install --global Microsoft.dotnet-interactive --version 1.0.115407
>   dotnet tool install --global dotnet-interactive
>   dotnet tool install --global dotnet-interactive --version 1.0.115407

```
Failed to install tool package 'microsoft.dotnet-interactive': Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\*\.dotnet\tools\.store\.stage\mfbifbk3.jlo\microsoft.dotnet-interactive'.
Tool 'microsoft.dotnet-interactive' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET Core tool.
The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
You mistyped the name of the tool.
For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool
```

> dotnet --info

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.201
 Commit:    b1768b4ae7

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.18362
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.3
  Commit:  4a9f85e9f8

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.604 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.802 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you are not quite running the latest of .NET Core SDK version (or runtime): if you are able on your particular machine, install the latest version (depending on your version of Visual Studio).  This *might* cure your problem.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

My configuration via `dotnet --info`, as the tools install correctly on Visual Studio 2019.  If you have updated your .NET Core then the other major difference is the Windows version; not sure that would be significant:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.201
 Commit:    b1768b4ae7

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19041
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.3
  Commit:  4a9f85e9f8

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.511 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.513 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Comment: Updated with latest .NET Core SDK, same issue, thank for trying

Comment: Do you see a .dotnet\tools\.store folder under your local user folder?  This is modified when the Interactive tools are installed.

Comment: @moxede3067  I have added my version info as part of my answer.

Comment: yes I have the same version 3.1.201 and yes I have the C:\Users\*\.dotnet\tools\.store\.stage folder

Comment: Are there any files in the .dotnet\tools\.store folder?  The structure is there on my machine but no files.  I deleted the folders then installed the dotnet Interactive tool and the folders were recreated with a successful install.

Comment: the .store folder contains a .stage folder and the .stage folder is empty, .store folder does't contains anything else, which folder did you delete?

Comment: .Store and below.

Comment: I deleted .store and below, re-executed same issue